# Minio K8S Operator - disk placement

Tags: kubernetes, storage, minio

Running minio operator on K8S is the solution i need to be able to create many minio tennats (installs) so serve my needs.  Its ability to make managing erasure encoding and all the configurations is great.
For the disk under minio it creates PVC on K8S using the storage class you choose.

We currently using Rook-CEPH to provide a distributed file system across the compute nodes.  This is using erase encoding.

So Minio is using EC ontop of Rook-Ceph EC - so everything is being storaged many many time, so super inefficient.

Does anybody know os a storage subsystem (CSI) that would allow minio to place its PV on different physical underline drive, as you would for a single minio server on physical hardware ?

Seems the missing key part of the puzzle ...

Answer (score 1):

weeks of look and immediately after i post this i find the answer !!

So DirectCSI would seem to be the answer
https://github.com/minio/directpv

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFTQmHpIsfQ